# Error creating bean with name 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory': Cannt resolve ref to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa, jira-rest-java-api

My ms rest api existing code implemented with jpa repository and on top of this code I am implementing 2 more endpoint where I will need to use jdbc template for oracle  and impala jdbc template as well , I have created one repository configuration class as well to refer respective datasource in the form of bean, when I am running pod by placing impala datasource in repository configuration then getting below exception. How to rectify this error? I have added hibernate core n entity manager library it is not working for me.

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument

I tried by adding hibernate core and entity manager library but it did not work for me.